# Tor fails to run on Windows 10 Build 16241 64 bit

Tags: configuration

I installed Tor on a Windows 10 Insider Build but it fails to run.  I opened Taskmanager but failed to detect any activity from Tor.  Tor has run successfully 'out of the box' under earlier builds but not under builds since 16226.  Is there a configuration issue?

I tried running in compatible mode and with admin rights to no avail.  The Tor version is configured for Windows, i.e not under Cygwin or MinGW.   The 'vanilla' version of Firefox runs, but not the TOR configured version.  I've been unable to find any console log files.

Comment: can you paste the log from console/cmd? What exactly the way you're doing it? standalone dot-exe or Cygwin or MinGW?

Comment: the version being used is the stand-alone dot-exe rather than through Cygwin or MinGW.

Comment: There are no console log files.  Can you advise what program need to be run to generate the required information?

Comment: The latest 'vanilla' version of Firefox runs without any difficulties.

Comment: Just run it in cmd.exe - the program is tor.exe and give it no arguments. It should start on a reasonable defaults and print all the logs to the console

Comment: Alexey,  Sorry to report despite running Firefox.exe (size 337,920) in the top directory and also tor.exe (size 3,405,824) in a lower directory produced absolutely nothing!  Regards,

Comment: it looks like you have got a fake tor.exe - I have already met such a thing when helping a person: tat tor.exe even tried to mimic real tor.exe output! So - get the "Expert bundle" from TorProject.org, **check the signatures** and extract it into c:\tor folder. Msg me after - I'll tell you what to do next

Answer (score 0):

So - thanks to moderator - the question is reopen. What's your situation looks like is a fake distribution of Tor or TorBrowser. It sounds weird, but I've helped a person about a year ago with the exactly the same problem: *tor.exe* binary was replaced and did not worked as supposed to, but it have tried to imitate the Tor's real console output and even passed something through! I suspect it was even trying to wiretap the data, so I hope you haven't tried anything privacy-sensitive so far. Here is what you need to do - please follow it step by step and I think your problem will be fixed as well. If some part of the problem will remain - feel free to drop a line and we'll fix it all! So - shall we begin?

- First of all - pack your "fake tor distribution" in an archive for further investigation and delete the folder after the archive was made. Tor distributions are not requiring any registry or service tasks, so just removing the folder will be fine.
- This step is kind of optional, but - as a precaution - run a full antivirus check with a *proper* antivirus. Who knows what exactly was in that fake distro. If you're using a crap Like Esen NOD32 or any of Kasperskiy's products - REMOVE IT, it's a crapware, spying for you. Under the windows I do recommend BitDefender or Sophos - in both the SSL traffic inspection is turned on by default, but you can turn it off and it actually turns off. Sophos is more like a PRO-tool, so if you're not so experienced in a system administration area - no problem, just use BitDefender. SSL inspection there is turned off in Web protection gear sign.
- Now you go to TorProject full downloads page https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en and downloading the Expert Bundle, **not** the browser one. You get the exe **and** the dot-sig file. It's a digital signature that is elaborated not just for authenticity ferification, but also for intergrity purposes, i.e. the distro you'll about to download was not modified on-flight. After that use [this tutorial from TorProject](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) to verify the signatures. As you'll verify it all - you'll extract the zip into *c:\tor* folder. You can change the drive letter, but change the following lines as well then. Do **not** use any space-containing, non-english or long names for a directory - it will save you tons of time! After doing this you'll have 2 folders from zip - *Tor* and *Data* as *c:\tor\Tor* and *c:\tor\Data*. Create a folder *c:\tor\local* and leave it empty.
- Next step is to create a very basic config file for Tor. It does have a very reasonable defaults, but let us just be specific. Create file *c:\tor\Tor\torrc* - *without any extension*, just name it `torrc`. If you have any difficulties with that - create it as `torrc.txt` and replace it in lines below. The contents of this file will be simple and straightforward as well:

  ```
  RunAsDaemon 0
  FastFirstHopPK 0
  AllowSingleHopCircuits 0
  EnforceDistinctSubnets 1
  UseEntryGuards 1
  DisableAllSwap 1
  DataDirectory c:\tor\local
  GeoIPFile c:\tor\Data\Tor\geoip
  GeoIPv6File c:\tor\Data\Tor\geoip6
  Log notice stdout
  SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9050
  ExitPolicy reject *:*
  ExitPolicy reject6 *:*
  DNSPort 127.0.0.1:53
  ```

Cool, but what does it means? Basically, we're about to store the local instance data in *c:\tor\local* subfolder, i.e. in case of future updates you just *safely* overwrite the Data and Tor folders as you need and leaving the instance data intact. We instruct Tor to avoid disr swap and usage as good as possible - nowdays we have enourg RAM on computers to run Tor: Raspberry Pi B+ with 512Mb and one core runs Tor just perfect without any need in swap, so your PC will do as well. We're instructing Tor to run in foreground, not as a service and log everything to the console - so if something is wrong, we will see it. We prohibit any traffic exiting from the node and telling where to get a copy of MaxMind GeoIP base - it's free edition is distributed with Tor.

- Next we need to run our Tor :) Create a batch file - like `torrun.bat` with the next lines in it:

  ```
  @echo on
  cd c:\tor\Tor
  C:\tor\Tor\tor.exe -f C:\tor\Tor\torrc
  pause
  ```

  Remember I was talking about torrc.**.txt** instead of just torrc ? If you did txt file - a line `C:\tor\Tor\tor.exe -f C:\tor\Tor\torrc` goes to be `C:\tor\Tor\tor.exe -f C:\tor\Tor\torrc.txt`

Run this - and if you'll see `Bootstrapped 100%` line - you're in! Use Firefox and [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) add-on to divert all the traffic through SOCKS at 127.0.0.1 port 9050 and *don't forget to click checkbox to resolve DNS via proxy*. Feel free to ask any further questions! If your Tor will not bootstrap to 100% - send the console log via pastebin.com

Comment: Can you explain why you think that @JGI has a 'fake distribution'?

Comment: @JensKubieziel because of the odd thing that he described - tor.exe if runned in console DOES prints something, AT LEAST. And the asker has stated clearly "There are no console log files" - that was quite similar to the situation I helped to solve. When the fake exe was given a *-f* key with the config - it did not succeeded in running it, but tried to mimic the output. So - the tutorial I gave has actually solved the problem that time, and I think it will fix the things up this time too.

Comment: Dear Alexey, sorry for the delay - work intervened!  Deleted the original exe version and downloaded the 'expert' version.  initially ran Tor.exe directly without creating the torrc and bat files and achieved Bootstrapped 100% Done.  then created and ran the torrc and bat files  with limited success!  the console output suggests reading config failed due to malformed IP.  (The fake distribution was the files from the Tor site not any mirror!!)

Comment: without using torrc or the bat file running tor then firefox appears to work, however it is unclear whether the browser is running under under tor.

Comment: Please post the console errors and your torrc. If you have got the messages now in console - it means that an expert bundle is working

Comment: D:\Users\jgire\Downloads\tor-win32-0.3.0.9\Tor>d:\users\jgire\downloads\tor-win32-0.3.0.9\Tor\tor.exe -f d:\users\jgire\downloads\tor-win32-0.3.0.9\Tor\torrc 
Aug 04 14:08:56.794 [notice] Tor 0.3.0.9 (git-22b3bf094e327093) running on Windows 8 with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2k and Zlib 1.2.8.
Aug 04 14:08:56.794 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 04 14:08:56.856 [notice] Read configuration file "d:\users\jgire\downloads\tor-win32-0.3.0.9\Tor\torrc".

Comment: Aug 04 14:08:56.856 [warn] The FastFirstHopPK option is deprecated, and will most likely be removed in a future version of Tor. Changing this option does not make your client more secure, but does make it easier to fingerprint. (If you think this is a mistake, please let us know!)
Aug 04 14:08:56.856 [warn] The AllowSingleHopCircuits option is deprecated, and will most likely be removed in a future version of Tor. Almost no relays actually allow single-hop exits, making this option pointless. (If you think this is a mistake, please let us know!)

Comment: Aug 04 14:08:56.856 [warn] Malformed IP "*.*" in address pattern; rejecting.
Aug 04 14:08:56.856 [warn] Couldn't parse line "*.*". Dropping

Comment: Can you please use a pastebin.com? It takes all the long logs and makes them available via link. The 2 messages you've sent are not full log. And where is your torrc?

Comment: Try to use a : instead of dots in ExitPolicy. I had a mistype here, editing the answer

Comment: I've never used pastebin before.  A paste has been made with the title Tor.  torrc is located in the same Tor directory as tor.exe and the various .dll files.  John

Comment: changed ExitPolicy as suggested.  The output file is similar.

Comment: A pastebin gives you an URL - to jump directly to the paste - can you post it?

Comment: by the way - just check it - do you have a dot in your config

Comment: Assuming I've done everything correctly the URL should be https://pastebin.com/T3PdNX66 this is for the unmodified torrc file (with :)

Comment: the URL for the file generated from the modified torrc file is https://pastebin.com/7RZgC0iM

Comment: it says "Malformed policy 'reject6 *.*'." - so replace a dot with ":"

Comment: looks like you haven't replaced it - can you send your bat-file as well?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/q4KCyMWt has copy of rc and bat files

Comment: a dumb test - try to put `Exitpolicy` instead of `ExitPolicy` - what will it be? or if it fails - try to comment `ExitPolicy` lines by putting a `#` as a first character on that strings

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HevFX8Uq. are for completeness.  Will now try the dumbtest. Back is a minutes or so.

Comment: kk! I'm here too - so let's fix this! The error messages are just like you're editing the wrong `torrc` - i.e. in your torrc are absolutely working settings: I have **the exactly the same** two lines in mine - and it works for a 1 year+

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mMPjAKuM  The dumb test 1.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UDsRU2YX. Dumb test 2

Comment: comment the line DNSPort and go with "dumb test 2" config

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AsCLxNKq.  torrc and output file

Comment: well, that's weird... try commenting DisableAllSwap line - and if it boots use the `User xxx` directive as **the very last line in config** to swith from administrator to the unprivileged user

Comment: Well, commenting out DiableAllSwap has caused the terminal window to freeze and no output file to be created.

Comment: freeze? like what? can you use Alt-PrintScreeen when the window is selected and send a screenshot?

Comment: sorry - I closed the window and investigated the directory.  it appears to have done something.    The machine was waiting for a Y/N reply but not seeing the screen this was hidden.   See dumb test 2b  https://pastebin.com/iAqPhg5W

Comment: so retry and make a log, please.

Comment: The local directory has been created alongside tor and data.

Comment: how do you wish the log to be created - I thought this had been sent on pastebin or are you looking for something different.

Comment: if directories are created and you can see in console "Bootstrapped 100%" message - it means it's working

Comment: typing tor.exe to run the tor browser produces the original list of error messages.

Comment: attempting to run Firefox from within windows fails with The proxy server is refusing connections

Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.

    Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
    Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working.

Comment: to get Firefox to work the terminal window has to remain open.

Comment: yes, because Tor runs in foreground

Comment: OK - so is everything now working?  I assume the torrc file should remain modified with the four lines commented out.  The Tor Browser remains inoperable.  The latest Windows Build is 16257.

Comment: do you have an antivirus software installed? if so - then what exactly? You need to create a user "tor" without ANY elevated privileges, change the ownership of everything in `d:\users\jgire\downloads\tor-win32-0.3.0.9` and below to it, add as the **very last line of the torrc config** a line like `User tor` and try to uncomment DNSPort line. You'll run the bat file from the Administrator's rights - and it will drop the privileges to user "tor" just to keep you safe. If you don't have any DNS server on your localhost and it will fail to bind to 127.0.0.1:53 - that's a reason to check your PC

Comment: I currently rely on Windows Defender and system backups to avoid software conflicts.  (Yes I know its not the most reputable solution).

Comment: WinDefender is not conflicting with Tor as my VM tests are showing. Try to run Tor as a service via RunAsService or other stuff - **and make sure to drop to an unprivileged user** via `User xxx` directive as the **very last string in torrc config**

Comment: I'm getting the following error:Aug 06 14:51:22.756 [warn] Switching users is unsupported on your OS.
Aug 06 14:51:22.756 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Problem with User value. See logs for details.
Aug 06 14:51:22.756 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

Comment: OPS... upgrades, ffs! then comment the User string and DNSPort as well... and run it from an unprivileged user - just for a pre-caution. I do recommend you to migrate Tor to the directory layout I proposed in my answer - is seemed to be the less glitchy for years

Comment: :-)  OK.  I've been running the file from an unprivileged user account.  I understand the directory layout you proposed.  I will create a top-level account under the C: system drive this keeping my user files on a separate partition.  Windows 10 doesn't give you this option on initial configuration :-(.

Comment: you're welcome! feel free to ask further questions if you'll have ones - I'm glad to help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63684/discussion-on-answer-by-alexey-vesnin-windows-10-build-16241-64-bit-tor-fails).